# python get request bearer auth token + access key

Tags: python, django, request

I have tried access the data using post man with bearer token and access key please see screenshot. now i wanted to know How to add accesskey in header on a request in pyhon i have already added the bearer token.
code

```
 headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer sdfjkdsjfs088gftdd'
        test = requests.get('http://blah.blah/api/1.0/blah', headers=headers)
```

[image: image 1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional items to the header by just adding additional key-value pairs to your `headers` dictionary:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer sdfjkdsjfs088gftdd",
    "accesskey": accesskey,  # provided accesskey is defined somewhere 
}
```

and then you can make the same request as before:

```
test = requests.get(url='http://blah.blah/api/1.0/blah', headers=headers)
```